# Variable was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error in several methods for several variables (all of which are vectors):

```
error: ‘parent’ was not declared in this scope
```

I've tried wrapping my method implementations inside of "namespace DisjointSubsets { ... }", but that causes other problems. It seems to only do this for vectors, and I've tried adding a "#include vector" at the start of the cpp file, it didn't change anything.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef UNIVERSE 
#define UNIVERSE 
#include <vector>
class DisjointSubsets { 
    public :
        DisjointSubsets ( unsigned numberElements = 5 ) ;
        unsigned findDS ( unsigned ) ;
        bool unionDS ( unsigned , unsigned ) ;
    private :
        vector<unsigned> parent ;
        vector<unsigned> rank ;
        unsigned size ;
} ;
#include "DisjointSubsets.cpp"
#endif
```

And here is an example of one of the methods I wrote in the cpp file (which has no #includes):

```
unsigned DisjointSubsets::findDS(unsigned index) {
    return parent[index];
}
```

(Changed the method to be non-functional, but still illustrate the kind of line that would cause a problem. Just in case someone else working on the assignment stumbles across this.)

Comment: This seems a bit inside out, what's the rationale behind the header file include the source file?  Usually you'd want the cpp file including the hpp file (or at least I would!).

Comment: I don't know; I'm just using the header file that I was given. It might have something to do with the way the makefile was written.

Comment: If you ever get multiple difinitions error when compiling remember that you are including the cpp in the header. This "trick" is sometimes used when using templates with diferent compilers, when some support the `export` keyword for templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `std::vector<unsigned>` instead of just `vector<unsigned>` to declare `parent` because `vector`is declared in the `std` namespace.
Therefore you could also use `using namespace std;` before declaring the class.

However most people I know would discourage you from using the second form in a header file.
See [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5) for a more elaborate discussion on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I thought it had to be a problem with the code I was writing, but I guess instructors can also make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

`vector` is in the `std` namespace.  Use `std::vector` or put a `using namespace std;` after your `#includes`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include .cpp files like this and expect it to work. That code is compiled independently, as well as as a part of other translation units. When you attempt to compile, that C++ code is compiled- but you didn't include the declaration. Unless the class is a template, the .cpp should include the .h, not the other way around.